# Conditionally removing rows from a matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, rows

I'm working with a sizeable set of data, but before moving on with my work I'd like to remove all rows whose values in one column is less than 10.

My data.frame has two columns, each with 427 rows. Without luck, I've tried...

```
for (i in vals[, 1])    # vals is the name of my data frame
{                       # I want to test the condition on the values in 
                          the first column
    if (i < 10)
    {
        vals <- vals[-i, ]
    }
}
```

When I run my script, I get an error saying: "-i: invalid argument to unary operator"

I'm not sure if it makes a difference (I'm still very new to using R), but I'll also add that this for-loop is nested in a much bigger one. Thank you!

Comment: Emily, one point to take away from this is R's ability to do things efficiently on an entire vector at once. In this case, `vals[[1]] < 10` would return a vector of `logical`, indicating which values meet the condition. The only thing missing (and not addressed in the answer below) is the presence of `NA` in your data; I'm guessing `any(is.na(vals[,1]))` is false, but if it is true then you'll need logic like `vals[ !is.na(vals[,1]) & vals[,1] >= 10,]`. (@12b345b6b78 ... feel free to add that constraint to your answer, I feel like I'm peppering you :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
vals <- vals[vals[, 1] >= 10, ]
```

Comment: Invert the logic, those are the rows to *remove*.

Comment: I've been following your responses! Thank you both for helping :) I'm still a little stuck because, for whatever reason, this is only recognizing the first 12 rows in column 1 as being >= 10 (which they are)...but around a 1/3 of these values are >= 10, so I'm not sure what's going on there :(

Comment: I also have no NA values in there!

Comment: How are you viewing the output? Could it be truncated? Did you extend the query in any way (which could limit the number matching rows after your logic is evaluated)?

Comment: I type the name of the table (so, vals) into the Console to see. I also tried just typing in "vals[[1]] >= 10" the Console to check the booleans and even there, only the first 12 values have TRUE and all the remaining 415 values have FALSE

Comment: Emily, we don't have your data, so anything we say is speculation. If you want something more meaningful for your data, please post the output from `dput(head(vals[1],n=...))` where `...` is enough to show rows that "should" be less than 10 but are not filtered out.

Comment: I've figured it out!! Now the above solution is working! :) Thank you both!!! I was having a data conversion problem... simply needed to use is.numeric() first

Comment: Hello, I have a question - could I use this solution for several columns?
Something like  `vals <- vals[vals[, 1:5] >= 10, ]`